# Pandas get all rows by max values for the second index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I'm trying to get the row with highest frequency. I counted the frequency of which department each user go to, but now I need to associate each user to a department they frequent which would be the two index columns department and department_id.

[image]
[image]

[image]

-Edit
Please forgive my stupidity. This drop box is a link to the csv file. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ttnmraxptpcw61c/user_department_freq.csv?dl=0

Comment: No, no, no, do not post your data as image...

Comment: right, I'm going to post the dataframe as a csv,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sort_values`, the `groupby` with `tail`

```
s=df.sort_values('order_id').groupby(level=0).tail(1)
```